# C# XML- Linq Query where multiple elements of same name exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I was using below code when my XML has a single element of 'HTTPSamplerProxy' now I have multiple elements with the same name and I want all to store.

```
XElement HTTPSamplerProxy = doc.Descendants("HTTPSamplerProxy").FirstOrDefault();
        path = (string)HTTPSamplerProxy.Elements("stringProp").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "HTTPSampler.path").FirstOrDefault();
        domain = (string)HTTPSamplerProxy.Elements("stringProp").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "HTTPSampler.domain").FirstOrDefault();
        method = (string)HTTPSamplerProxy.Elements("stringProp").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "HTTPSampler.method").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239002/xml-members-initialization-for-xmlserializer-using-c-sharp/52240644#comment91455313_52240644

Answer (score 0):

Your method [Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb360635(v=vs.110).aspx) returns already a collection of node `HTTPSamplerProxy`.

So just eliminate `FirstOrDefault`, get the collection and loop for each node.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> proxies = doc.Descendants("HTTPSamplerProxy");

foreach(var proxy in proxies)
{
}
```